# Is it possible to open someone's Xcode snapshot in my Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, snapshot

My boss sent me a Xcode Snapshot of the project that he is working on, but I don't know how to open it and I am not sure if it's possible to open it. Can someone teach me?